# Porting Cocos2d 1.0 to Cocos2d 2.0

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, box2d-iphone

I got one old game and I tied to update Cocos2d 2.0 SDK. I got some compilation error.

```
b2Vec2 gravity;
gravity.Set(0.0f, -10.0f);
self.world = new b2World(gravity, true);
```

> Error: No matching constructor for initialization of 'b2World'

When I change this to below code then works but Box2D debug shapes are not drawn.

```
self.world = new b2World(gravity);
```

How to initialize Box2d world in right way that show debug shapes?

Comment: use GLESDebugDraw. world->SetDebugDraw(m_debugDraw); and also enable the Flags for debug draw too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace the GLESDebugDraw files with those found in a newly created cocos2d 2.0 + Box2D project. Your version is still using GL ES 1.1 commands which don't work in cocos2d 2.x

Answer (score 1):

Finally I got debug shape by replacing this draw function and GLESDebugDraw files.

```
-(void) draw
{
    [super draw];
    ccGLEnableVertexAttribs( kCCVertexAttribFlag_Position );
    kmGLPushMatrix();
    self.world->DrawDebugData();
    kmGLPopMatrix();
}
```